# Getting the error message from BadRequest

Tags: angular, typescript, error-handling

I'm trying to get my Sign up form to display the errors coming back from API when a user sends invalid data.

You can see here how the error response looks in the console: [console ss](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSbHt.png)

This is what i tried to do in RegisterComponent.ts:

```
onSubmit() {
    this.userService.register(this.registerForm.value).subscribe(response =>{
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/shop');
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
      this.errorMessage = error.errors;
      if(this.errorMessage) for(let err of this.errorMessage) console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

And I added this into the html:

```
<ul *ngIf="errorMessage">
   <li *ngFor="let error of errorMessage">
      {{error}}
   </li>
</ul>
```

But it did not work as expected. Seems like the errorMessage variable is empty and I want it to display "An account already exists with this email".
How do I properly get the error message?

Comment: Probably something missing in your userService.register. Can you add that code?

Comment: @MikeOne This is the register method from user service: ` register(values: any){
    return this.http.post(this.url + 'users/register', values).pipe(map((user: IUserModel) =>{
      if(user) {
        localStorage.setItem('token', user.token);
        this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
      }
    }))
  } `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting it right, but storing it wrong. You might want to try `this.errorMessage = error.error;`

No s in error. Also, you do not have to loop the error, since it is a string. If you loop it, you will each letter one by one.